# How can I attach the corresponding HTML ending to each piece of scraped text?

Tags: python, regex, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In short I am making a program which scrapes specific citations from a list of URLs. I need the result to also have the MR number from the corresponding URL ending, added to each scraped citation.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools

#DEFINING TWO FUNCTIONS TO HELP FINDING ONLY THE WANTED CITATIONS:
MATCH_ALL = r'.*'


def like(string):
    """
    Return a compiled regular expression that matches the given
    string with any prefix and postfix, e.g. if string = "hello",
    the returned regex matches r".*hello.*"
    """
    string_ = string
    if not isinstance(string_, str):
        string_ = str(string_)
    regex = MATCH_ALL + re.escape(string_) + MATCH_ALL
    return re.compile(regex, flags=re.DOTALL)


def find_by_text(soup, text, tag, **kwargs):
    """
    Find the tag in soup that matches all provided kwargs, and contains the
    text.

    If no match is found, raise ValueError.
    """
    elements = soup.find_all(tag, **kwargs)
    matches = []
    for element in elements:
        if element.find(text=like(text)):
            matches.append(element)
    if len(matches) == 0:
        raise ValueError("No matching citations were found")
    else:
        return matches

#DEFINING URL LIST:

base_URL = "https://sis1.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/GAP/"
mrn = ["MR4044696", "MR2900886", "MR3169623", "MR4180136"]
url_list = []

for i in range(len(mrn)):
    url = (base_URL + mrn[i] + '.html')
    url_list.append(url)
    
print(url_list)

all_content = []
all_matches = []

#THIS IS THE LOOP WHICH ITERATES THROUGH AND GATHER THE RESULTS:

for url in url_list:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    match = (find_by_text(soup, 'GAP', 'li'))
    all_matches.append(match)
print(all_matches)

OUTPUT

"[[<li>
  The GAP Group, GAP – groups, algorithms and programming, version 4.10, Available from http://www.gap-system.org, 2018. 

</li>], [<li>
  The GAP Group, <span class="MathTeX">$GAP$</span><script type="math/tex">GAP</script> groups, algorithms, and programming, version 4.4.12 (2008), http://www.gap-system.org. 

</li>], [<li>
  Distler, A., Mitchell, J. D. (2011). <span class="it">Smallsemi - A Library of Small Semigroups.</span> http://url.com, Oct A GAP 4 package [5], Version 0.6.4. 

</li>, <li>
  The GAP Group, (2008). (http://www.gap-system.org). <span class="it">GAP–Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.4.12.</span>
</li>], [<li>
  The GAP Group, 2019. GAP – Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.10.1; https://www.gap-system.org. 

</li>]]"
```

I need each result to have the corresponding MR number added to the beginning, for instance:

```
MR4044696, The GAP Group, GAP – groups, algorithms and programming, version 4.10, Available from http://www.gap-system.org, 2018. 

MR2900886, Distler, A., Mitchell, J. D. (2011). <span class="it">Smallsemi - A Library of Small Semigroups.</span> http://url.com, Oct A GAP 4 package [5], Version 0.6.4. 

MR3169623, The GAP Group, (2008). (http://www.gap-system.org). <span class="it">GAP–Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.4.12.</span>
```

I think I need to add something like:

```
for i in range(len(url_list)):
    matching_mrn = mrn[i]
```

in the `find_by_text` function but wherever I add it everything breaks and it does not work well.
For the love of god I cannot make this work, please help me out and a massive thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a dictionary rather than a list, then iteraterate through that and attaching that value to the `match`. Another wya to do it is slice the url and use the mrn you created in that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools

#DEFINING TWO FUNCTIONS TO HELP FINDING ONLY THE WANTED CITATIONS:
MATCH_ALL = r'.*'


def like(string):
    """
    Return a compiled regular expression that matches the given
    string with any prefix and postfix, e.g. if string = "hello",
    the returned regex matches r".*hello.*"
    """
    string_ = string
    if not isinstance(string_, str):
        string_ = str(string_)
    regex = MATCH_ALL + re.escape(string_) + MATCH_ALL
    return re.compile(regex, flags=re.DOTALL)


def find_by_text(soup, text, tag, **kwargs):
    """
    Find the tag in soup that matches all provided kwargs, and contains the
    text.

    If no match is found, raise ValueError.
    """
    elements = soup.find_all(tag, **kwargs)
    matches = []
    for element in elements:
        if element.find(text=like(text)):
            matches.append(element)
    if len(matches) == 0:
        raise ValueError("No matching citations were found")
    else:
        return matches

#DEFINING URL LIST:

base_URL = "https://sis1.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/GAP/"
mrn = ["MR4044696", "MR2900886", "MR3169623", "MR4180136"]
url_dict = {}

for i in range(len(mrn)):
    url = (base_URL + mrn[i] + '.html')
    url_dict[url] = mrn[i]
    
print(url_dict)

all_content = []
all_matches = []

#THIS IS THE LOOP WHICH ITERATES THROUGH AND GATHER THE RESULTS:

for url, mrn in url_dict.items():
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    match = (find_by_text(soup, 'GAP', 'li'))[0]
    match.insert(0, NavigableString("%s, " %mrn))
    all_matches.append(match)
print(all_matches)
```

**Output:**

```
[<li>MR4044696, 
  The GAP Group, GAP – groups, algorithms and programming, version 4.10, Available from http://www.gap-system.org, 2018. 

</li>, <li>MR2900886, 
  The GAP Group, <span class="MathTeX">$GAP$</span><script type="math/tex">GAP</script> groups, algorithms, and programming, version 4.4.12 (2008), http://www.gap-system.org. 

</li>, <li>MR3169623, 
  Distler, A., Mitchell, J. D. (2011). <span class="it">Smallsemi - A Library of Small Semigroups.</span> http://blacklistshorteners.com/, Oct A GAP 4 package [5], Version 0.6.4. 

</li>, <li>MR4180136, 
  The GAP Group, 2019. GAP – Groups, Algorithms, and Programming, Version 4.10.1; https://www.gap-system.org. 

</li>]
```